# uniquely ng-bind-html in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-bind-html

I have my html something like this,

```
<div ng-controller='gridDataController as gridDataCtrl'>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in gridData" id="{{row.record_no}}">
            <td ng-bind-html="editInputA">{{row.a}}</td>
            <td ng-bind-html="editInputB">{{row.b}}</td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <button ng-click="edit(row.record_no)" >edit</button>
                    <button ng-click="update(row.record_no)" >update</button>
                    <button ng-click="delete(row.record_no)" >delete</button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want the edit function to add input box to a particular row the edit button is been clicked, is there any angular way of doing it, also I though I would want the input box added to have a unique id, so I can trigger it for updating the edited text. I am looking for best angular practice, as I am new to it. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe best way to do it is to hide the input and show it with ngShow (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)

```
<body ng-app="ngAnimate">
    <button ng-click="showInput= !showInput" >edit</button>
    <div>
        <div class="check-element animate-show" ng-show="showInput">
        <input class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" id="newInput">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I adaped the example from ngShow for you to use it with ngClick:

https://plnkr.co/edit/Cgo5bFgNxhJUVbTwjzu8?p=preview

Another way would be to use
    var input = var element = document.createElement("input");

but using ng-show seems to suite your needs better